# jquery / css slide down but child element should not move

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery to slide a `div` down. Inside the `div` as 4 list items with images and content in them.

When the parent `div` slides up and down, the content inside moves up and down. However, I would like the content to remain static, so the `div` is like a screen being pulled over the content inside.

There is an example of how I would like this to work here: http://www.google.co.uk/nexus/

Click on the "Choose a device" link.

You should see the images inside not moving up and down but remaining static.

jQuery slideUp / slideDown doesnt do this.

This illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/uqdGe/1/

The red columns move up and down with the parent container.  I want them to remain static

Comment: Please post code here.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of the SlideUp/SlideDown - http://jsfiddle.net/terLP/1/

Comment: I have posted a jsFiddle that illustrates the problem

Comment: @MartyWallace your fiddle has no javascript code

Comment: it does for me.  that is odd

Comment: ok try now, http://jsfiddle.net/uqdGe/1/

Comment: @MartyWallace the content moves in the second fiddle. the OP wants it to keep it's position and be revealed / hidden by the container animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `slideToggle()` scales the padding as it collapses `.container`. Instead of putting padding on the container, try using a margin on the `li`:

http://jsfiddle.net/xFGPb/1/

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 2em 10px 0 0;   /* add 2em margin top */
    background: red;
}

.container {
    background: green;
    padding: 0 2em 2em;    /* remove 2em padding from the top */
}

ul {                       /* css reset */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: and here there's another quirk ;) note how the green container background jumps up/down when you toggle (before animating)

Comment: yes, this is almost there but the margin does cause a wierd behaviour with the jump unfortunately

Comment: Oops, updated; I had to reset the UL margin/padding (specifically, just margin). If you want to retain that spacing, perhaps add it on to the li margin top.